# Why didn't the links open to a new tab/window?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, hyperlinks

Why is the links which are provided in questions and answers did not open a new tab/window. I personally feel that, this would be a great feature and did not require right click to open new tab/window or pressing back and forth button. What is your opinion?

I had searched this in meta and I didn't find anything regarding this.

Comment: Personally, I'm quite happy that the links don't all open in a new tab/window. If I do want to open one in a new tab, I can just hold Ctrl and click the link (in Firefox and Chrome, at least).

Comment: This has been tagged as [meta-tag:status-declined]: [Make links posted by users open in a new window](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2275/168244)

Comment: Yes @Werner, thanks for that link.

Comment: I think this would be useful for the search box

Comment: I believe it is often considered a Bad Thing when webpages open links in new windows; see http://uxdesign.smashingmagazine.com/2008/07/01/should-links-open-in-new-windows/ for instance.

Comment: I prefer using the middle mouse button instead of holding down Ctrl while clicking. I think this is the default setting now on Windows for the middle button.